# Trouble getting DropDownListFor to work on EditorFor in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, editorfor, html.dropdownlistfor

I've got a pretty simple problem that has a solution I'm not able to find.

Given the following model:

```
public class InfoViewModel
{
    public SelectList States { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("State")]
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

The following works fine in my view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, Model.States)
```

However, if I try to pull this into an editor template (named "SelectList"), such as:

```
@model System.String
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, ViewData["selectList"])
```

And then use `EditorFor` to build the dropdown list:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.State, "SelectList", new { selectList = Model.States })
```

It fails with the following error:

```
'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<string>' does not contain a definition for 
'DropDownListFor' and the best extension method overload 
'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor<TModel,TProperty>
(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, 
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TProperty>>, 
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>)' 
has some invalid arguments
```

I'm having a hard time understanding the difference between these two.  I've tried various workarounds to troubleshoot, and either get the same error, or something else.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks...,your quetion are usefull for as my answer///

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no such overload:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, ViewData["selectList"])
```

The second parameter of the `DropDownListFor` helper musty be a `SelectList`. So:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, (SelectList)ViewData["selectList"])
```

Comment: Thanks, Darin, that was exactly it. I should have realized that.